# Django: Find amount of parameters starting with the same word

Tags: python, django, request

In my Django app's views.py I want to write a function to find the amount of optional parameters that begin with 'item' that are in the request

```
def get_items(request):
```

Note: The request passed into this function could have various amounts of optional parameters starting with 'item' with a number like so: &item1=, &item2=, &item3=..etc along with other optional parameters that don't start with 'item'

So a request could be similar to any of these:

```
/myapp/data/&item1=foo&item2=bar&item3=baz&otherParam=other
/myapp/data/&item1=baa&otherParam=other
/myapp/data/&item1=bla&item2=baa&otherParam=other
```

I know I could do the following (but this would require me to know the number of 'items' ahead of time):

```
request.GET.get('item1')
request.GET.get('item2')
request.GET.get('item3')
```

Is there a way to find out the number of 'item' optional parameters? (So 3 in the first request above, 1 in the second and 2 in the third)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `len(request.GET)` to find count of key-value pairs in `request.GET` object.

Comment: I just updated my question. I forgot to mention there are other optional parameters that don't start with 'item'

Answer (score 0):

A QueryDict responds to all the usual dict methods, so you can iterate over the keys directly - combine that with a list comprehension and call `len` on it:

```
len(k for k in request.GET if k.startswith('item'))
```

Or, if you actually need the matching values, use `items` with a dict comprehension:

```
items = {k: v for k, v in request.GET.items() if k.startswith('item')}
```

Note, you haven't shown how your frontend is generating these values but you probably don't want to do this in the first place. A QueryDict can have multiple values for each key, so you could send all the data in the same `item` parameter:

```
/myapp/data/?item=foo&item=bar&item=baz&otherParam=other
```

Now you can just do `request.GET.getlist('item')` to get `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
len([value for key, value in request.GET.items() if 'item' in key.lower()])
```

Comment: To help readers understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the problem